# How to add ItemAddEventHandler for multiple folders in outlook using C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

We have added some rules in outlook to move item to some folder depends on some condition.

example: if email sender is xyz@gmail.com and subject contains particular keyword lets say "news" then move that email to folder "NewsFolder", if email sender is prq@gmail.com then move that email to "InterestFolder" folder. etc.

I want to perform some action when item is added to particular folder, I have added configuration in app.config for checking folder name. I tried with itemAdd event handler but I failed.

below is my code.

```
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
Outlook.Items items;

Private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, system.EventArgs e)
{
           //configuration will come from app.config file
        
            string configuration="news,NewsFolder|interest,InterestFolder"; //comma separated by keyword, folder name
            string[] conf = configuration.split('|');
            foreach(string singleConfiguartion in conf)
           {
                  string[] config = singleConfiguraiton.Split(','); 
                  string configFolderName= config[1].ToString(); //get folder name from configuration
                  Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = inbox.Folders[configFolderName];
                  Outlook.MAPIFolder currentFolder = inbox.Folders[configFolderName];
                  items= currentFolder.Items;
                  items.ItemAdd+= new Outlook.ItemEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(ItemAddedEventHandler);
           }
    
}    

void ItemAddedEventHandler(Object item)
{

}
```

This way is worked if I want to add event handler for "Inbox" folder only. But I want to add Event handler for "NewsFolder" and "InterestFolder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper class that holds the Items collection and implements the `ItemAdd` event handler. You can then keep these wrappers in a list. Off the top of my head:

```
private List<FolderWrapper> _folders = new List<FolderWrapper>();
...
foreach(string singleConfiguartion in conf)
{
    ...
    _folders.Add(new FolderWrapper(currentFolder));
}

public class FolderWrapper
{
    private MAPIFolder _folder;
    private Items _items;
    public FolderWrapper(MAPIFolder folder)
    {
        _folder = folder;
        _items = _folder.Items;
        _items.ItemAdd += ItemAddedEventHandler;
    }
    private ItemAddedEventHandler(object Item)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"new item is created in {folder.Name}");
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is making last folder in configuration i read as default folder when I open outlook.   How to solve this ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "It is making last folder in configuration i read as default folder". You really need to show your code.

Comment: For example string configuration="news,NewsFolder|interest,InterestFolder , in this configuration, last folder read is "interestFolder" , and when I open outlook, it make this as folder as default one.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by "it make this as folder as default one". Do you mean it becomes the default Inbox folder? Or it becomes selected in Outlook? Or that you only receive notifications from that folder?

Comment: When I open outlook, it opens that folder by default.. I found it...it was because I was setting up current folder there as Outlook.MAPIFolder currentFolder = inbox.Folders[configFolderName];